# Explode pandas dataframe list of lists (of points) into dataframe with pairs of points

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, `bike_path_df`, that contains a few columns, of which one is called `coordinates`. The format of `coordinates` is a list of lists, where each inner list is a pair of latitude and longitude coordinates, and the i'th and i+1'th element of the list of lists denote a straight line bike path segment connecting the two points i and i+1.

For example:

`bike_path_df.iloc[0]['coordinates']`

yields the following:

```
[[149.12482362501234, -35.17695800091904], # Point A of line 1
 [149.12481244481404, -35.177008392939385], # Point B of line 1, point A of line 2
 [149.12480556675655, -35.17703489702785], # Point B of line 2, point A of line 3
 [149.12481021458206, -35.17706139012856], # etc...
 [149.12483798252785, -35.17709736965295],
 [149.12489568437493, -35.17714846206322]]
```

After some effort, I've written a clumsy loop that will allow me to pair each point with it's neighbours:

```
all_list = []
for list_of_points in bike_paths_df['coordinates']:
    result = [ [ list_of_points[i], list_of_points[i+1] ] for i,j in enumerate(list_of_points) if i+1 < len(list_of_points) ]
    all_list.append(result)
```

The output from the above resembles something like

```
[[[149.12482362501234, -35.17695800091904],[149.12481244481404, -35.177008392939385]],
 [149.12481244481404, -35.177008392939385], [149.12480556675655, -35.17703489702785]],
 ...]]]
```

But converting `all_list` to a `pd.Series` object can return NaN when I try to add it back to the original dataframe (I believe because Series is expanding the list of lists, so the shapes are no longer equal).

Ideally I'd like to have each set of four points on a dataframe row, with the other data for that path repeated for each set of four points, such that it would resemble:

```
>>bike_path_df.head()

name    coordinate_pair
Path1   [A1_long, A1_lat, B1_long, B1_lat]
Path1   [B1_long, B1_lat, C1_long, C1_lat]
Path1   [C1_long, C1_lat, D1_long, D1_lat]
Path1   [D1_long, D1_lat, E1_long, E1_lat]
Path2   [A2_long, A2_lat, B2_long, B2_lat]
Path2   [B2_long, B2_lat, C2_long, C3_lat]
...
```

Does anyone have any advice?

I've also uploaded a few rows of the actual data I'm working with in CSV format here: https://github.com/Ecaloota/BikePathInfrastructure-ACT as "bike_paths_progress.csv"

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, use `zip` and `explode`

```
df = pd.read_csv('bike_paths_progress.csv', index_col=0)
df['coordinates'] = pd.eval(df['coordinates'])
df = df.join(df['coordinates'].apply(lambda x: [[i[0], i[1], j[0], j[1]]
                                      for i, j in zip(x, x[1:])])
                              .explode().rename('coordinate_pair'))
```

Output:

```
>>> df.loc[81, 'coordinate_pair']
81    [149.12482362501234, -35.17695800091904, 149.12481244481404, -35.17700839293...
81    [149.12481244481404, -35.177008392939385, 149.12480556675655, -35.1770348970...
81    [149.12480556675655, -35.17703489702785, 149.12481021458206, -35.17706139012...
81    [149.12481021458206, -35.17706139012856, 149.12483798252785, -35.17709736965...
81    [149.12483798252785, -35.17709736965295, 149.12489568437493, -35.17714846206...
Name: coordinate_pair, dtype: object
```

Comment: @Ecaloota. I updated my answer. Can you check the outcome, please?

Comment: both your updated answer and the previous one appear to do exactly what I needed, thank you very much for your help!